# Is there a way for shell script to know which program has executed it?

Tags: shell-script, shell, process, debugging

In *nix world, is there a way for shell script to have information about which program has executed it?

---

Example:

`/path/to/script1 /path/to/script_xyz`

in this imaginary scenario, `script_xyz` would have path information (`/path/to/script1`)

**or**

process PID

of entity that have executed it.

*Note: I'm curious about different solutions and approaches, I don't expect exactly this to be actually possible*

Comment: Your subject asks which program **executed** the script. But your actual question seems to be asking for the **interpreter** of the script. Which of the two is your question really about?

Comment: @kasperd You are right. Question was about program, but that's actually interpreter. That's why I had feeling that this is not possible in the first place.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There's often confusion between process forking and execution.

When you do at the prompt of a `bash` shell.

```
$ sh -c 'exec env ps'
```

The process *P1* issuing that `$` prompt is currently running `bash` code. That `bash` code forks a new process *P2* that executes `/bin/sh` which then executes `/usr/bin/env`, which then executes `/bin/ps`.

So *P2* has in turn executed code of `bash`, `sh`, `env` and `ps`.

`ps` (or any other command like a script we would use instead here) has no way to know that it has been executed by the `env` command.

All it can do is find out what its parent process id is, which in this case would be either *P1* or `1` if *P1* has died in the interval or on Linux another process  that has been designated as a [*subreaper*](/q/250153) instead of `1`.

It can then query the system for what command that process is *currently* running (like with `readlink /proc/<pid>/exe` on Linux) or what arguments where passed to the last command it executed (like with `ps -o args= -p <pid>`).

If you want your script to know what invoked it, a reliable way would be to have the invoker tell it. That could be done for instance via an environment variable. For instance `script1` could be written as:

```
#! /bin/sh -
INVOKER=$0 script2 &
```

And `script2`:

```
#! /bin/sh -
printf '%s\n' "I was invoked by $INVOKER"
# and in this case, we'll probably find the parent process is 1
# (if not now, at least one second later) as script1 exited just after
# invoking script2:
ps -fp "$$"
sleep 1
ps -fp "$$"
exit
```

`$INVOKER` will ([generally](/a/119991)) contain a path to `script1`. In some cases, it may be a relative path though, and the path will be relative to the current working directory at the time `script1` started. So if `script1` changes the current working directory before calling `script2`, `script2` will get wrong information as to what called it. So it may be preferable to make sure `$INVOKER` contains an absolute path (preferably keeping the basename) like by writing `script1` as:

```
#! /bin/sh -
mypath=$(
  mydir=$(dirname -- "$0") &&
  cd -P -- "$mydir" &&
  pwd -P) && mypath=$mypath/$(basename -- "$0") || mypath=$0

... some code possibly changing the current working directory
INVOKER=$mypath script2
```

---

In POSIX shells, `$PPID` will contain the pid of the parent of the process that executed the shell at the time of that shell initialisation. After that, as seen above, the parent process may change if the process of id `$PPID` dies.

`zsh` in the `zsh/system` module, can query the *current* parent pid of the current (sub-)shell with `$sysparams[ppid]`. In POSIX shells, you can get the *current* ppid of the process that executed the interpreter (assuming it's still running) with `ps -o ppid= -p "$$"`. With `bash`, you can get the ppid of the current (sub-)shell with `ps -o ppid= -p "$BASHPID"`.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, a program can know who its parent is.

To illustrate, let's create two bash scripts.  The first one reports its PID and starts the second script:

```
$ cat s1.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo s1=$$
bash s2.sh
```

The second script reports its process ID, the PID of its parent, and the command line used to run the parent:

```
$ cat s2.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo s2=$$ PPID=$PPID
echo "Parent command: $(ps -o cmd= -q $PPID)"
```

Now, let's run it:

```
$ bash s1.sh
s1=17955
s2=17956 PPID=17955
Parent command: bash s1.sh
```

As you can see the second script does, in fact, know the PID of its parent.  Using `ps`, that PID reveals the command line used to invoke the parent.

For a discussion of PPID in more depth, see Stéphane Chazelas's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/297775/53604).

Comment: Thanks. Running your example scripts I get `s1`, `s2` and `PPID` values but then, in multiple lines after `ERROR: Unsupported SysV option.` and several lines with additional explanation and - empty value for `Parent command`

Comment: John's using some ps feature that's not available (or is provided differently) on your platform, check your ps(1) manual page.

Comment: @Miloshio I tested the above using `ps` from the `procps-ng` package, version 3.3.12.  As Jasen suggested, you are likely using a different version which may require a different syntax for printing the parent's command line.  Try `ps -f | grep $PPID`.